# Disable language code in URL for default language

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I'm using drupal 7 and i18n module.

I select the user language with the language code in the URL like this:
mysite.com/fr/node/1
mysite.com/en/node/1
etc

The default language is French.

How could I manage to get only "mysite.com/node/1" when selected language is French?
For now, I only get "mysite.com/fr/node/1".
If I go to the root of my website "mysite.com", and I overlay the links, they're all pointing to "mysite.com/fr/...".

Is there anyway I could disable the `/fr/` as the default language?

I tried playing around with the selection's rule weight, without success.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Under "admin/config/regional/language" you will see the list of languages. Click the edit link to edit the languages. In the edit screen, change the "Path prefix language code". If French is your default language, then keep this value blank for French.

Comment: This way works great with one exception. There is a side effect with the module "Administration menu". After deleting the language code all links of this menu were broken. In this case you have to remove manually the language code in the adressbar and clear the cache.