# Remove language prefix from files URL

Tags: i18n-l10n, .htaccess, uri

I have a drupal installation in a sub folder (demos/drupal) and it supports two languages (english -default- & arabic). I imported the drupal content from an old site. My problem is that the language prefix (i.e. en or ar) is added to the url of all images and this causes the images to not appear. for example: `http://www.mysite.com/demos/drupal/en/sites/default/files/image.png)`.

Can I remove the 'en' and direct all urls to "sites/default/files..etc" using htaccess rules?

I can't modify the content and find/replace the urls  in the database so I'm looking for a solution to avoid that.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: The reason is the old site didn't have a second language and it is being added and prepared right now on the development server. I'm afraid playing with the DB would mess up the old and new content. So I want to maintain the old/new site links and items as much as possible to make life easier when I re-upload the site to the production server.

Comment: Another way to fix this problem [enter link description here][1]
That decision is more correctly.

  [1]: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38043/disable-language-code-in-url-for-default-language/38051

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `mod_rewrite`, here's what to put in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1
```

Btw. this has little to do with Drupal, it is either an Apache thing or a DB thing (depending on how you decide to solve it).

Comment: I had to add another `/` in front of the `$1` to prevent my whole path `user/example/domains/example.com/private_html` from being appended to the url. So I used `RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1`.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: For some reason this didn't work for me. The working solution is: RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]